# Should classes replace constructor functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

As far as I know classes are just syntactic sugar for old style constructor functions. Does this mean that I should completely replace the constructor functions with classes?
Example:

### Constructor function

```js
function person(name,age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
}
person.prototype.logAll = function() {
 console.log(this.name,this.age);
};

var rachel = new person("Rachel Green", 52);
rachel.logAll();
```

### Class

```js
class person {
 constructor(name,age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
 }
 logAll() {
  console.log(this.name,this.age);
 }
}

var rachel = new person("Rachel Green", 50);
rachel.logAll();
```

Are those two completely equivalent?

Comment: The advantage of classes is that they're easier to manage. Inside your class you can define constructors, destructors, getters, setters, which can then be used in your entire application. In the example above they are equivalent but I strongly recommend the use of classes.

Comment: Classes are easier to use and to mantain and gives you less pain with the  so called `this`. Coming from the vanilla javascript, I would recommend you to use **classes** where possible for several reasons: 1) Any other programmer that is not familiar with javascript can find a bit of OOP in your code. 2) Easier to mantain. 3) Easier to read. 4) Offers the same functionalities of the old prototype syntax. So, overall, in this specific case they both give the same exact output but, for the sake of reading and maintenance, use **classes** where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you're using them for. Don't forget that a lot of older browsers don't support classes, so usually you're best sticking to older JS style code if you're writing client side JS that needs to run in the majority of browsers.

If you don't care about old browsers, or this is server side JS, then I would use classes.

Classes are easier to understand for most developers (outside of JS), and (opinion) they're simpler and nice to write.

As an aside, I've written a lot of ES6 JavaScript recently, and it feels like a much more grown up version of JS to me (don't flame me). I would honestly say that anytime where it makes sense, and it won't impact your deliverables, try and use the new features; that's what they're there for!

Comment: No need to stick with older JavaScript, just use a transpiler.

Comment: That's true to a point, but unless I'm mistaken there's a few es6 features that don't really have an equivalent in es5